# I want to rewrite URL http://www.website.com/picture.php?id=12 to http://www.website.com/picture/id/12

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Url Rewrite My url is I want to rewrite URL  http://www.website.com/picture.php?id=12 to http://www.website.com/picture/id/12

Comment: What does "is not proper working" mean? Does it do nothing at all? Does it rewrite in a wrong manner? What is the `abc` doing in the rule and the leading slash?

Comment: Also from your question I am not sure what you try to do. url rewriting cannot alter the links you send out by means of php. It can only rewrite _incoming_ requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^picture.php$ /picture/id/%1? [L,R]
```

Comment: i use this code but. Not Proper working . this work like /picture/id/12?id=12 i want  only /picture/id/12 please Help Me

Comment: this works so that  input `/picture.php?id=12` redirected to `/picture/id/12`. do you want reverse?  that is easier `RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^picture/id/(.+)$  /picture.php?id=$1 [L,R]`

Comment: It not perfect  working according to my requirement . it gives result  picture/id/13?id=13 but i want  like  picture/id/13

Comment: I forgot question sign to remove a query string. my bad. try now

Comment: I want to rewrite url picture.php?id=13 To picture.php/id/13 with .htaccess i answer is not proper work according to my need. it gives result picture.php/id/12?id=12

Comment: Last 20 hours it doesn't save ?id= in redicrected url

Answer (score 2):

You can Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^picture.php$ /picture/id/%1? [L,R]
```